# How can I get circulating supply for crypto currency?

Tags: mining, altcoin

I am looking for an API, where I can get the circulating supply for all crypto currencies?

For now, I found this: https://altcoinmarketcap.com/api.
The problem is that if the site go down , I can not get my circulating supply data.

Is there are more sites that can provide me API fot this data?

Thanks

If I don't want to be dependant on that site, Where can I get the data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

https://coinmarketcap.com/api/

I think the coinmarket is the big boy.

Comment: is possible to calculate circulating supply without using an API?

Comment: circulating supply is a weird concept.  It makes sense w/ Bitcoin (total issued now / 21M)...but not really for a lot of tokens.  Many times circulating supply, it's just (the total supply - the team supply); often times when the team's isn't even locked...  Other times it has to do with vested supplies and amount locked...it's all different by each token and sort of meaningless to compare

Comment: Thank you very much, now I think I understand it, if I'm not mistaken, more than a formula it is a personalized analysis that should be done for each specific project since the variables can change and it is a concept which is not fully defined