# BEP20 Price and Market Cap API

Tags: external-api, bsc

I am trying to find an API where I can the Market Cap of Binance Smart Chain tokens. I know that Market Cap = Circulating Supply * Token price. I am able to get the token price from PancakeSwap api. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get circulating supply for crypto currency?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25704/how-can-i-get-circulating-supply-for-crypto-currency)

Answer (score 2):

> I am able to get the token price from PancakeSwap api.

This is the PancakeSwap price, which is one particular market, and may or may not be similar to the aggregate price across multiple markets (which is what sites like CoinMarketCap and CoinGecko show).

CoinGecko has a [free API](https://www.coingecko.com/en/api) that will return the data you want, though only includes the more popular tokens. I doubt there's an API that will return all the data you want for lesser-known tokens.

For example, for the PancakeSwap token (CAKE):

> https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/pancakeswap-token

Returns a JSON object with the fields:

```
"market_data": {
    "current_price": {
        ...
    }
}

"circulating_supply": ...
"market_cap: {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I Forgot to say that i also wanted the API to contain also the new/unpopular coins. At the moment I am trying to get the total supply from bscscan and subtracting the tokens that are in the burn addresses. Unfortunately the market cap that i get does not match poocoin or bogged finance